# Delle and not dei or degli

Tags: grammar, pronouns, nouns

Why is it delle in the following sentence and not dei or degli?

> Nessuno di queste proposte stabilisce incentivi che premino la qualità **delle** prestazioni, anziché la quantità.

In which cases would it be dei or degli?

Comment: You should study some rudiments of Italian grammar, rather than asking several single questions. Even obtaining the answers, you'll still miss the general picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Prestazioni* is a feminine plural, so its article is *le*; *di* + *le* becomes *delle*.

You'd have *dei* or *degli* for nouns with article *i* or *gli*, respectively (which are always masculine plural), e.g. *dei cani* or *degli orsi* (*il cane*, *i cani* / *l'orso*, *gli orsi*).